# Why is my while loop infinite?

Tags: c++, c, function, while-loop, warnings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Too many arguments.\n", argc );
return 1;
}

double n;
n = atof(argv[1]);

if (n<0) {
    printf("Negative argument.\n");
return 1;
}

double r;
r = n;
int iteration;
iteration = 0;

while(calcError(n,r)<1e-6) {
    iteration = iteration +1;
    r = (r + n/r)/2;
    printf("  %d. sqrt(%f)~= %f,error=%e\n",iteration,n,r,calcError(r,n));  
}

printf("sqrt(%f)=%f to  six places\n",n,r); 

return 0;
}

int calcError (double n, double r) {

double delta;

delta = n-r*r;
delta = delta > 0 ? delta : -delta;

return 0;

}
```

Running this code generates an infinite while loop. I also get a warning stating: format '%e' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 5 has type 'int' [-Wformat]. Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

`calcError` always returns `0`, so

```
while(calcError(n,r)<1e-6)
```

is as good as

```
while(0 < 1e-6)
```

or

```
while(true)
```

As for the warning, the compiler says exactly what's wrong: `calcError` returns an `int`, but the format string provided by you (`%e`) need a `double`. This will yield Undefined Behavior. Changing the return type as below will fix this issue.

Looking at your code, I think you wanted to loop as long as the error was larger than `1e-6`. If that's correct, you might want to modify your `calcError` to be as follows:

```
int calcError (double n, double r)
{
    double delta;

    delta = n-r*r;
    delta = delta > 0 ? delta : -delta;
    return delta;
}
```

which can be shortened to

```
double calcError(double n, double r)
{
    return fabs(n-r*r);
}
```

and change the condition of your loop to loop until it's smaller:

```
while(calcError(n,r) > 1e-6)
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. However, running the code with that change still generates the same warning. There is no longer an infinite while loop, it seems to bypass the while loop completely now and displays: sqrt(24.000000) = 24.000000 to six places

Comment: I think you want to loop as long as the error is larger than your epsilon, so use this: `while(calcError(n,r)>1e-6)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Oqw54hodZugBWEnn) is exactly what you wanted. By the way, note that your invocation of `calcError` for the `printf` has arguments in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

In your `calcError()` function, you have,

```
return 0;
```

So in your expression, `calcError()` will always be zero.

and, `(0 < 1e-6)` is always true.

Answer (score 0):

You have `while(calcError(n,r)<1e-6)` and `calcError` always returns 0, so of course your loop will go on forever. I think you meant to have `calcError` return `delta` instead of `0`.